# Can we display visitor's uploaded images WordPress homepage instantly?

Tags: wordpress, customization

How can I display user submitted images on other pages of WordPress site instantly. Currently I'm using Advanced custom fields plugin but that needs admin access.

Comment: How does the user submit the content?

Comment: through user submitted posts(usp plugin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the settings page of the plugin you can use the option "Auto Publish" and add the shortcode to the page you want it to show up... for more help use the plugin support / forum here: https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/user-submitted-posts